# Redirect standard output to file

Tags: c, linux

I have to modify this code. The child process should redirect standard output to text file.

I think that I should do sth with dup2 and exec but I don't know what.

I read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipes-and-FIFOs.html#Pipes-and-FIFOs) ref and also [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Duplicating-Descriptors.html#Duplicating-Descriptors).

But it didn't helped me, probably I'm doing sth wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main ()
{
    int fds[2];
    pid_t pid;
    /* Create a pipe. File descriptors for the two ends of the pipe are placed in fds. */
    /* TODO add error handling for system calls like pipe, fork, etc. */
    pipe (fds);
    /* Fork a child process. */
    pid = fork ();
    if (pid == (pid_t) 0) {
        /* This is the child process. Close our copy of the write end of the file descriptor. */
        close (fds[1]);
        /* Connect the read end of the pipe to standard input. */
        dup2 (fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        /* Replace the child process with the "sort” program. */
        execlp ("sort", "sort", NULL);
    } else {
        /* This is the parent process. */
        FILE* stream;
        /* Close our copy of the read end of the file descriptor. */
        close (fds[0]);
        /* Convert the write file descriptor to a FILE object, and write to it. */
        stream = fdopen (fds[1], "w");
        fprintf (stream, "This is a test.\n");
        fprintf (stream, "Hello, world.\n");
        fprintf (stream, "My dog has fleas.\n");
        fprintf (stream, "This program is great.\n");
        fprintf (stream, "One fish, two fish.\n");
        fflush (stream);
        close (fds[1]);
        /* Wait for the child process to finish. */
        waitpid (pid, NULL, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have done with `dup2` is connecting the parent's `stdout` to child's `stdin`,  leaving the child's `stdout` without a redirection. so the childr would print sorted strings to `stdout`. 
what you should do next is to open a textfile , and do a `dup2` with it's `stdout`. such as something before `execlp`

```
int outfd=open("/tmp/output",O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT,0600);
dup2(outfd,STDOUT_FILENO);
execlp ("sort", "sort", NULL);
```

you will also need to `#include <fcntl.h>` to have file flags.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. What i was doing wrong was editing/deleting dup2 while i should add another. Thank you once more :)